# I lost data while changing os from windows to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: data-recovery

I lost data while changing OS from windows 7 to Ubuntu 18.04.How can I recover my data from partitions in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

First of all shutdown your computer and don't load your newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 until recovery process will be completed. This point is most important for your at the moment.

Next you have to load your computer from Ubuntu Live USB and to try to recover your data using two utilities: `testdisk` and `photorec`, which is part of `testdisk`.

Start from `testdisk` in Ubuntu Live following the beginners guide [How To Recover Deleted Files In Linux](https://itsfoss.com/recover-deleted-files-linux/) and continue with the article [PhotoRec - Recover Deleted or Lost Files in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/photorec-recover-deleted-lost-files-in-linux/)

Always prefer to use external drives to save your recovered data - it's best practice of data recovery.

Comment: Thanks all. I tried max but no luck. I get back my data from outside. It costed me